# Paypal select amount for Hosted Donation button in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, donations

I am working on rails 4 application. I need to give payment options for Donation button.

I need to create radiobutton as well as textbox to enter amount of payment for Donation.

My code is

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxxxxxxxx">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donateCC_LG.gif"     border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Here I enter value of amount field by jQuery (code is not posted) so it is not empty ("").

But on the second step the amount I submit in hidden field is not shown.

I google it some people say one can not enter amount on hosted button means it would be fixed every time.

Some people say create the buy now button reference => https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/get-started/donate-button-text-field

What should I do is it possible with hosted button?

Should I change my code ?

Comment: How are you defining the value of the button? If you're appending a form like above, surely you can just populate the `amount` field?

Comment: you mean to say How I enter value in amount hidden field ?

Comment: No I mean - how do you want to populate that field? It's just an HTML form - surely you can make it visible & populate it either from Rails, or with HTML?

Comment: I want to populate with HTML. I am sending request to https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr here on donation amount field is empty it should be filled with the amount that I passed via hidden field.

Comment: YEs - let me explain. You've got an HTML form on your site. Surely you can fill the `value=""` of your `amount` element with whatever value you want? My question was how do you wish to determine the value you want to associate with it?

Comment: I want to show the value in  Is above written code is right? OR Can you provide me the code form that you use.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you use the PayPal hosted buttons you can't change the amount related information. Hosted buttons are secure in the terms that nobody can fiddle with the amount. Changes to the amount for hosted buttons can only be done thru account or via [API's](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_wpsbuttonmgrapinvp.pdf) . If you are implementing a solution where you need to change the amount dynamically you should consider using the clear text button or You can dynamically generate the encrypted using the [API's](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_wpsbuttonmgrapinvp.pdf)

However the variables related to :**address ,cancel/return/image/ipn url ,item name/invoice id/custom/quantity** can be overridden by passing the variables for hosted buttons.

Comment: Can you please provide me any link or reference from where I can do apply this thing?

Comment: I pasted the link in my answer also: https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/pp_wpsbuttonmgrapinvp.pdf